# how can i force my page to wait for iframe to be rerendered

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I use JS to change `src` of hidden `iframe` in my page. Then I get element of this `iframe` and use it in my page. How can I froce my page to wait for this iframe reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `onload` on the iframe element, and put your code in there.